# I tried ordering modules, now everything is one under the other

Tags: component

I was trying to remove a module from footer and replace it with another one. However, now everything is broken. The modules are positioned one over the other. Top on top. Can anyone advise what i am doing wrong ? Thanks[image]

Comment: Have a look at the settings for your previous footer module and make sure everything matches up, such as Module Class Suffix

Comment: I...I sent everything to Trash and started the footer from scratch...

Comment: Not to worry, you can retrieve the trashed modules. In the Module Manager on the left hand side, set the "Status" to "Trashed". This is of course you didn't delete it from the trash too

Comment: Yes yes its still here, and they do have a unique Module Class Suffix. Post your answer below and i will mark it as "answered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've trashed your module but it's not permanently deleted. To get it back, in your Module Manager, on the left hand side, simply set the **State** to **Trashed**. This will show you your Footer module that you deleted before.

Now that you have it back, have a look at the the default setting that have been applied, primarily the Module Class Suffix which will most likely be the candidate.

Apply the same Module Class Suffix and and other setting to your new module

Hope this helps